# Saving XML-Data in UserSettings

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I'm trying to save some XML-Data in my UserSettings (Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettings) in a .NET Winforms Project. Is there a Possibility to do that or would it be better to save this Data in a seperated File?

Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: Let us know how you got on - I'd be interested in your implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store an XML document's string representation in a setting of type String.  To save the document, load it into an XmlDocument and set the setting to the value of the XmlDocument.OuterXml property.  To retrieve it, create a new XmlDocument and use its LoadXml method to parse the string into an XML document.

This is usually a bad idea.  Not because there's anything intrinsically wrong with storing an XML document as text within another XML document -- there isn't.  But most settings that you access through the UserSettings property are single values.  You're introducing a mode of operation where a single setting can now contain an arbitrary number of actual settings.  That's not what most people who read your code are going to expect.

As with a lot of things that give code a bad smell, this may be perfectly fine in your specific implementation.  I can imagine circumstances in which I'd do it.  But in most cases, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous project I had a similar idea but decided to keep the xml files separate.

The xml files can be embedded resources, and their file names can be referenced in the Settings file.

I think this is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Answers. As a conclusion, I've decided to extract this stuff into another xml-File which I store in the Resources.